# Using SMO DependencyWalker to generate script but getting foreign key constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am using SMO's `DependencyWalker` to walk through my dependencies and script inserts.

```
var insertScripter = new Scripter(server)
{
     Options =
     {
          ScriptSchema = false, 
          ScriptData = true,
          SchemaQualify = false
     }
};

var tables = db.Tables.OfType<Table>()
    .Where(tb => tb.IsSystemObject == false)
    .Cast<SqlSmoObject>()
    .ToArray();

var dependencyWalker = new DependencyWalker(server);
var dependencyTree = dependencyWalker.DiscoverDependencies(tables.ToArray(), DependencyType.Parents);
var dependencies = dependencyWalker.WalkDependencies(dependencyTree);

foreach (var dependency in dependencies)
{
  foreach (var s in insertScripter.EnumScript(new[] { dependency.Urn}))
  {
    writer.WriteLine(s); 
  }
}
```

For some reason I still get foreign key constraints when running the script?
How is this possible?

Comment: I've not used this at all so may be completely wrong, but it looks logical to me that you should pass `DependencyType.Children` to `DiscoverDependencies()` instead of `DependencyType.Parents`. I think your tree is upside down.

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work (the online examples I saw all used `DependencyType.Parents`)

Comment: Silly question, but you don't have any circular dependencies in your database, do you (i.e. A depends on B, B depends on A)?

Comment: I ran the script found in http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2010/07/01/finding-circular-foreign-key-references/ to check but did not find any circular references

Answer (score 0):

Try using this form of the method, `DiscoverDependencies(UrnCollection, Boolean)` and set the Boolean to $false; it worked for me.

The comment of Rhumborl is on the right track with regards to the proper parameter.